# How to use _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable in tvOS?

Tags: debugging, uikit, focus, tvos

To debug the focus issues `_whyIsThisViewNotFocusable` method is available in the tvOS, But in debug in `shouldUpdateFocusInContext` with this command like this `po [mainView _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable]` or `po mainView _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable` it gives me error :

```
error: <EXPR>:1:9: error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
mainView _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable
```

So what is the correct use of _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable ?

I seen this question in some stack-overflow answers but because of less reputation i can't comment in that post/answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you're using swift so you shouldn't use obj-c in the debugger. Instead use:

```
po mainView.performSelector(Selector("_whyIsThisViewNotFocusable"))
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked , as on developer site they have written like Obj-c type i thought it works in both

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

`(lldb) po yourView.perform(Selector("_whyIsThisViewNotFocusable"))`

Also you can [Turn on Live Focus Logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/focus-based_navigation/debugging_focus_issues_in_your_app)

> In your Xcode project, select Edit Scheme and add
>   -UIFocusLoggingEnabled YES to the Arguments Passed On Launch section.

Check this [readme](https://github.com/NikKovIos/TvOS-Debug-Hints).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 11, you can use [UIFocusDebugger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifocusdebugger).